# Getting number of files in a partition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I wrote a code in C++ CLI which can loop through all files in the system. I want to know the number of files are existing in the system programmatically without counting the files one by one!
Also...Would that number be useful in scanning progress bar?

Comment: PS. why would you loop through all files? Use shadow copy + richcopy/robocopy? If you need full fs replication there are usually block level alternatives that have more viability

Comment: @sehe: I don't see any mention of copying, things like antimalware tools also need to visit every file on the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using NTFS, you can call the [`FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364569%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) IoControl to get a whole bunch of data for your volume. The number of files will be at most `MftValidDataLength / BytesPerFileRecordSegment`. Keep in mind that this is a maximum number of files that can be on the volume, so the actual number will always be less.

I would also hope that you'd be using [`FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364563%28VS.85%29.aspx) to read the files rather than walking the directory tree (which is inaccurate and error-prone). This thread has an example of somebody doing it in C#: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c1550294-d121-4511-ac32-31551497f64e/

Answer (score 1):

That would depend highly on the filesystem in use (and the administrative privileges held by the impersonated user :))

You might find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ntfs+statistics) or you can enhance your question with more details